# Zoom level wise radius change in Leaflet Heat

Tags: leaflet, javascript, heat-map

I am using leaflet.heat for creating heatmap with leaflet API.I have a highest intensity of 1.0 and lowest 0.0. I have created a getRadius function where I tried to change radius based on zoom scale. In zoom level 7 it showing very good result as I am trying to plot approximately half million of data. When I am increasing the zoom level the radius is not enough to visible expected result. Probably increasing the radius with zoom scale will be the solution. But the radius became static and its showing the value based on map loading zoom level. How could I change this?

```
function getRadius(){
            var radius;
            if (currentZoom === 7){
                radius=2
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 8) {
                radius = 4;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 9) {
                radius = 6;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 10) {
                radius = 8;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 11) {
                radius = 10;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 12) {
                radius = 12;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 13) {
                radius = 14;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 14) {
                radius = 16;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 15) {
                radius = 18;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 16) {
                radius = 20;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 17) {
                radius = 22;
            }
            else if (currentZoom === 18) {
                radius = 24;
            }
            return radius;
        }
var heatmap = L.heatLayer(allHeats, {
                    radius: getRadius(),
                    max: 1.0,
                    blur: 15,              
                    gradient: {
                        0.0: 'green',
                        0.5: 'yellow',
                        1.0: 'red'
                    },
                    minOpacity: 0.7
                }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for `zoomstart` events and use the `setOptions(options)` method on your layer. Code should be similar to this:

```
map.on('zoomstart', function(ev) {
    // zoom level changed... adjust heatmap layer options!
    heatmap.setOptions({
        radius: getRadius(),
        max: 1.0,
        blur: 15,              
        gradient: {
            0.0: 'green',
            0.5: 'yellow',
            1.0: 'red'
        },
        minOpacity: 0.7
    });
    // render the new options
    heatmap.redraw();
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about onZoomIn or zoomOut function. I am loading million of data. Is it going to call the data again? or it will redraw the heatLayer from the existing data?

Comment: I had a look in the reference again (http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-event) and the event you should listen for is `zoomend`. I do not know how the redraw is realized. Just try it - I would be interested in the performance result.

Comment: the radius is not changing on 'zoomend'.

Comment: Probably you need `heatmap.redraw()` to actually use the new options?

Comment: if redraw then the data loading will take 2-3 more second and that will decrease the potentiality and beauty

Comment: What about changing `zoomend` to `zoomstart` then? Changes should be applied by rendering the layer in the new zoom level...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75249/discussion-between-lars-and-devils-dream).